# Generate Pinterest Share Button That Specifies URL

Tags: social-networking, pinterest

I am trying to create a "pinterest share" button, but am running into a snag.

Currently, I have the pinterest button (generated from their [Widget Builder](http://business.pinterest.com/widget-builder/#do_pin_it_button)) appearing in a Lightbox. (For certain reasons, it must appear this way.)

The issue is the Lightbox code has direct linking on it, so the code for the lightbox window is something like: www.domain.com/#/social/4

Pinterest is picking up that URL (which has no images since it's just the lightbox) instead of the URL for the main page (www.domain.com).

Does anyone know how I can specify the exact URL to share via the pinterest button?

I have read some posts that said doing this would work:

```
<a href="http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://www.domain.com" class="pin-it-button" count-layout="none"><img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/PinExt.png" alt="Pin it" / ></a> <script type="text/javascript" src="http://assets.pinterest.com/js/pinit.js"></script>
```

However, specifying the URL does not seem to work at all. It appears to be totally ignored and has no impact.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a standard link and specify all the data in the parameters:

```
<a href="http://www.pinterest.com/pin/create/button/
        ?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fphotos%2Fkentbrew%2F6851755809%2F
        &media=http%3A%2F%2Ffarm8.staticflickr.com%2F7027%2F6851755809_df5b2051c9_z.jpg
        &description=Next%20stop%3A%20Pinterest"
        data-pin-do="buttonPin"
        data-pin-config="above">
        <img src="//assets.pinterest.com/images/pidgets/pin_it_button.png" />
    </a>
```

Source: http://developers.pinterest.com/pin_it/

Answer (score 0):

You can try using structured meta data and [Rich Pins](https://developers.pinterest.com/rich_pins/).